# Cocoa pods and Watchkit Extesion

Tags: ios, xcode6, cocoapods, watchkit

I try to build a WatchKit Extension for my app...

I Updated the pods file to look like this:

```
platform:ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

link_with 'my-team-ios', 'My Team WatchKit Extension'

def shared_pods
    pod 'DOSingleton'
    pod 'JSONModel'
    pod 'MagicalRecord'
end

target :'My App' do
    shared_pods
    pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.23.1'
    pod 'Reveal-iOS-SDK', :configurations => ['Debug']
    ... some more pods here...
end

target :'My Team WatchKit Extension' do
    shared_pods
end
```

How I install the pods and don't get an error...

But, when I build the App, I get this error:

```
ld: framework not found Pods
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What is my problem here?

Comment: Have you run `pod install`?

Comment: Are you opening the workspace or the project?

Comment: Sure, I open the workspace... It was already a pod project before. I just added the changes to support the "Watchkit Target"....

Comment: I guess by that time you found a solution. Do you mind to share it please?

Comment: how did you solved it?

Answer (score 14):

I'm using **Pod 1.2.1** and facing the same problem i.e. No such module `XYZ` and for anyone who came across the same issue here what I did to overcome it:

```
use_frameworks!

def shared_pods
    pod 'XYZ'
end

target 'MyApp' do
    platform :ios, '8.0'

    shared_pods

    pod 'Blah'
    pod 'blah'

end

target 'Watch Extension' do
    platform :watchos, '3.2'
    shared_pods 
end
```

I just added platform under each target e.g `platform :watchos, '3.2'` which was missing before and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

You need to open the xcworkspace file instead of the project file when using CocoaPods.

Comment: Sure, I open the workspace... It was already a pod project before. I just added the changes to support the "Watchkit Target"....

Answer (score 2):

The problem is when updating to cocoapods 0.36.x they are now creating Frameworks out of each pod library. See the [blog post about it.](http://blog.cocoapods.org/Pod-Authors-Guide-to-CocoaPods-Frameworks/)

This causes issues with any pod library that is dependent on other pods and how its referencing them in their import statements, or how your code is importing them as well.  The Pod process now turns them into frameworks and when they used to be imported as

`#import "ThisOtherPodClass.h"`

Now need to be imported as

`#import <ThisPodsFrameworkName/ThisOtherPodClass.h>`

Answer (score 2):

There is a new version of cocoa pods .38, that is designed to support WatchKit.  However, if you want to work with the current version, check o make sure that libPods.a is added to the Target, WatchKit Extension in Included Libraries and Frameworks.  Second, make sure that Pods.debug and Pods.release are added to Watchkit Extension in the General tabl

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3382

*neonichu commented on Apr 15, 2015
would start by making sure OTHER_LDFLAGS isn't overwritten with unnecessary things, both in the project and the targets.*

That  set OTHER_LDFLAGS  in buids settings solved my issus.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this lines

`target :'My App'`, `target :'My Team WatchKit Extension'`

and remove colons:

`target 'My App'`, `target 'My Team WatchKit Extension'`

Answer (score 0):

I found a "temporally solution" for me:
Switch back to CocoaPods 0.35

Now everything is working fine, with our any changes to my project / pod file (except removing the 'use_frameworks!')

I think, that should not be the final solution here...

A short test by upgrading again to 0.36 raises the same problem as before...

[Here is a link to the GitHub Issue:](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3382)

Answer (score 0):

Rename the target so it doesnt include any spaces -> MyTeamWatchKitExtension both in podfile and also in General -> Targets. This solved my problem