# How to add Alamofire pod to Apple Watch extension?

Tags: swift, cocoapods, apple-watch

I have an Apple Watch extension named "watchTest". I am trying to add `Alamofire` for this extension, but without success until now.

My Podfile:

```
source "https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git"

platform :ios, '9.3'

use_frameworks!

target 'buttonExample' do
    pod 'Alamofire'
end

target 'watchTest' do
    pod 'Alamofire'

    target 'watchTest Extension' do
        inherit! :search_paths
    end

end
```

Pod Install Log (the warning could be the source of the problem):

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using Alamofire (4.9.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 total pod installed.

[!] The `watchTest [Debug]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-watchTest/Pods-watchTest.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `watchTest [Release]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-watchTest/Pods-watchTest.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

WatchTest Extension InterfaceController.swift:

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import Alamofire

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        super.awake(withContext: context)

        // Configure interface objects here.
    }

    override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        super.willActivate()
    }

    override func didDeactivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
        super.didDeactivate()
    }

}
```

Error on compiling:

> watchTest Extension: No such module 'Alamofire'

Comment: Wild guess, but did you try to clean Xcode? That has a habit of fixing a bunch of problems :-)

Comment: Yes, cleaned the Derived Data folder and tried to set Legacy Build System. Unfortunately didn't help.

Comment: And I guess you opened the workspace, and not the project?

Comment: Yes, I double checked that.

Comment: Can you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29519536/cocoa-pods-and-watchkit-extesion)? It says to add `platform :watchos, 'version'` to the target.

Comment: It worked! Please post this as an answer so I can mark as accepted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29519536/cocoa-pods-and-watchkit-extesion) link. It shows that you must add `platform :watchos 'version'` to the target.

```
target 'watchTest Extension' do
    platform :watchos, 'version'
    pod 'Alamofire'
end
```

Comment: just for the reference, you should replace `'version'` with your WatchOS deploy version.

Answer (score 0):

Add pod under extension target not anywhere else

```
source "https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git"

platform :ios, '9.3'

use_frameworks!

target 'buttonExample' do
    pod 'Alamofire'
end

target 'watchTest' do
    pod 'Alamofire'

    target 'watchTest Extension' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        pod ‘Alamofire’
    end
end
```

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately the same problem happens